# How can I automatically visually number each webform component? e.g. 1) ... 2) ... 3)

Tags: 7, webforms

I am building a webform and would like to number each question (webform component). What is the automated way to do this (rather than number the component label text)?

Webform 3 (but may move to Webform 4 later).

I've searched a bit for this, but get results about phone number fields :/

Thanks for your time.

**Update**

I have clarified the question to state that I want to visually number the components, the numbers themselves would not be related to the component id, rather, they would be for the benefit of the user. It would be used to number the questions e.g.:

1. Question
2. Question

etc.

Comment: Why is this important? The component id cant be customized i believe

Comment: It's important because the webform that I am building is a series of questions and I'd like to number them. The numbers would be visible to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an entirely front-end solution with CSS counters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

I believe components are siblings of each other which would make this quite easy.

Comment: +1 that sounds like a great solution. I'll explore more and follow up. Alternatively I'd consider writing a hook using the webform api. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a presentational problem more than a back-end problem. I'd always lean towards CSS solutions for these kind of issues.